# REST call using curl taking to much time. Show as progress bar

Tags: 8

I'm getting information from a source using REST. Bellow is part of my code. Basically, there's a part where I have a `for loop` that can take 30 to 60 seconds to complete. It works but the user doesn't have feedback if the date is being fetched.

```
<?php
    function get_data($qc, $path) {
        $qc = curl_init();

        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($myarray); $i++) {
            curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_URL, "http://myurl/" . $path[$i] . "]}");

            $xml = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($qc));
            $json = json_encode($xml);
            $output_array = json_decode($json, TRUE);

            ...
        }
        return $output_array;
    }
?>
```

Is there a way that I can do this asynchronously? Show a progress bar or something?

I looked at this module - [Background Process](https://www.drupal.org/project/background_process) but I think this is not the way to do it.

Note: I know the size of `$myarray`

Thanks.

EDIT: Added all the code to the question:

```
<?php
function mymodule_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['home/QC'] = array(
        'title' => 'QC',
        'description' => 'QC Test',
        'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'page callback' => 'mymodule_qc',
    );
    return $items;
}

function mymodule_qc() {
    //create a new cURL resource
    $qc = curl_init();
    //create a cookie file
    $ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");

    //set URL and other appropriate options
    curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_URL, "http://myurl:port/qcbin/rest/is-authenticated");
    curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
    curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    //grab the URL and pass it to the browser
    $result = curl_exec($qc);
    $response = curl_getinfo($qc);

    if($response['http_code'] == '401') {
        $url = "http://myurl:port/qcbin/authentication-point/authenticate";
        $credentials = "username:password";
        $headers = array("GET /HTTP/1.1","Authorization: Basic ". base64_encode($credentials));

        curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_HTTPGET,1); //Not sure we need these again as set above?
        curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        //Set the cookie
        curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
        curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $result = curl_exec($qc);
        $response = curl_getinfo($qc);

        //The response will be 200   
        if($response['http_code'] == '200') {
            $out = "Authentication OK!";
            //Use the cookie for subsequent calls...
            curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
            curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            $name = "QC FOLDER NAME";
            $safe_name = rawurlencode($name);

            curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_URL, "http://myurl:port/qcbin/rest/domains/MYDOMAIN/projects/MYPROJECT/test-set-folders?query={name['" . $safe_name . "']}");

            //In this example we are retrieving the xml so...
            $xml = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($qc));
            $json = json_encode($xml);
            $out_array = json_decode($json, TRUE);

            $id = $out_array['Entity']['Fields']['Field'][0]['Value'];
            $path = $out_array['Entity']['Fields']['Field'][6]['Value'];

            // Get Test Sets:
            $testsets = get_testsets($qc, $path);

            // Save data to Drupal Database:
            xreport_qc_savedata($testsets);

            //Call Logout
            logout($qc,"http://myurl:port/qcbin/authentication-point/logout");
        }   else {
            $out = "Authentication failed";
        }
    }   else {
        $out = "Not sure what happened?!";
    }

    //Close cURL resource, and free up system resources
    curl_close($qc);
}

function get_testsets($qc, $path) {
    // GET TEST SETS:
    curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_URL, "http://myurl:port/qcbin/rest/domains/MYDOMAIN/projects/MYPROJECT/test-sets?query={test-set-folder.hierarchical-path[" . $path . "*]}");

    $xml = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($qc));
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $out_array = json_decode($json, TRUE);

    // Get all names and ids of testsets:
    $testsets = array();
    if (isset($out_array['Entity'][0])) {
        foreach ($out_array['Entity'] as $folder) {
            $id = $folder['Fields']['Field'][51]['Value'];
            $name = $folder['Fields']['Field'][54]['Value'];

            $testset = array($id, $name);
            array_push($testsets, $testset);
        }
    } else {
        $id = $out_array['Entity']['Fields']['Field'][51]['Value'];
        $name = $out_array['Entity']['Fields']['Field'][54]['Value'];

        $testset = array($id, $name);
        array_push($testsets, $testset);
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($testsets); $i++) {
    #for ($i = 33; $i < 34; $i++) {
        curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_URL, "http://myurl:port/qcbin/rest/domains/MYDOMAIN/projects/MYPROJECT/test-instances?query={cycle-id[" . $testsets[$i][0] . "]}");

        $xml = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($qc));
        $json = json_encode($xml);
        $testset_array = json_decode($json, TRUE);

        if (isset($testset_array['Entity'])) {
            $x = 0;
            if (isset($testset_array['Entity'][0])) {
                foreach ($testset_array['Entity'] as $testset) {
                    $testcase_id = $testset['Fields']['Field'][70]['Value'];
                    $testcase_week = $testset['Fields']['Field'][22]['Value'];
                    $testcase_mrid = $testset['Fields']['Field'][25]['Value'];
                    $testcase_build = $testset['Fields']['Field'][31]['Value'];
                    $testcase_status = $testset['Fields']['Field'][63]['Value'];

                    // Adds the TestSet Name to the same array level:
                    $testsets[$i][3][$x]['testcase_testset'] = $testsets[$i][1];
                    $testsets[$i][3][$x]['testcase_id'] = $testcase_id;
                    $testsets[$i][3][$x]['testcase_week'] = $testcase_week;
                    $testsets[$i][3][$x]['testcase_mrid'] = $testcase_mrid;
                    $testsets[$i][3][$x]['testcase_build'] = $testcase_build;
                    $testsets[$i][3][$x]['testcase_status'] = $testcase_status;

                    // Get testcase details:
                    $link = "http://myurl:port/qcbin/rest/domains/MYDOMAIN/projects/MYPROJECT/tests/" . $testcase_id;
                    curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_URL, $link);

                    $xml = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($qc));
                    $json = json_encode($xml);
                    $testcase_array = json_decode($json, TRUE);

                    $testcase_name = $testcase_array['Fields']['Field'][92]['Value'];
                    $testsets[$i][3][$x]['testcase_name'] = $testcase_name;
                    $x += 1;
                }
            } else {
                $testcase_id = $testset_array['Entity']['Fields']['Field'][70]['Value'];
                $testcase_week = $testset_array['Entity']['Fields']['Field'][22]['Value'];
                $testcase_mrid = $testset_array['Entity']['Fields']['Field'][25]['Value'];
                $testcase_build = $testset_array['Entity']['Fields']['Field'][31]['Value'];
                $testcase_status = $testset_array['Entity']['Fields']['Field'][63]['Value'];

                // Adds the TestSet Name to the same array level:
                $testsets[$i][3][$x]['testcase_testset'] = $testsets[$i][1];
                $testsets[$i][3][$x]['testcase_id'] = $testcase_id;
                $testsets[$i][3][$x]['testcase_week'] = $testcase_week;
                $testsets[$i][3][$x]['testcase_mrid'] = $testcase_mrid;
                $testsets[$i][3][$x]['testcase_build'] = $testcase_build;
                $testsets[$i][3][$x]['testcase_status'] = $testcase_status;

                // Get testcase details:
                $link = "http://myurl:port/qcbin/rest/domains/MYDOMAIN/projects/MYPROJECT/tests/" . $testcase_id;
                curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_URL, $link);

                $xml = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($qc));
                $json = json_encode($xml);
                $testcase_array = json_decode($json, TRUE);

                $testcase_name = $testcase_array['Fields']['Field'][92]['Value'];
                $testsets[$i][3][$x]['testcase_name'] = $testcase_name;
                $x += 1;
            }
        } else {
            // testset is empty
        }
    }
    return $testsets;
}

function logout($qc, $url) {
    curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_HTTPGET,1);
    curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    //grab the URL and pass it to the browser
    $result = curl_exec($qc);
}

function xreport_qc_savedata($testsets) {
    foreach ($testsets as $testset){
        if(isset($testset[3])) {
            $newarray = $testset[3];
            foreach ($newarray as $value){
                if (!empty($value['testcase_id'])) {$testcase_id = $value['testcase_id'];} else {$testcase_id = '';}
                if (!empty($value['testcase_testset'])) {$testcase_testset = $value['testcase_testset'];} else {$testcase_testset = '';}
                if (!empty($value['testcase_name'])) {$testcase_name = $value['testcase_name'];} else {$testcase_name = '';}
                if (!empty($value['testcase_week'])) {$testcase_week = $value['testcase_week'];} else {$testcase_week = '';}                    
                if (!empty($value['testcase_mrid'])) {$testcase_mrid = $value['testcase_mrid'];} else {$testcase_mrid = '';}
                if (!empty($value['testcase_build'])) {$testcase_build = $value['testcase_build'];} else {$testcase_build = '';}
                if (!empty($value['testcase_status'])) {$testcase_status = $value['testcase_status'];} else {$testcase_status = '';}

                $node = new stdClass();
                $node->type = 'content_qc';
                $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
                node_object_prepare($node);

                $node->title = $testcase_id;
                $node->field_x_qc_testcase_id[$node->language][]['value'] = $testcase_id;
                $node->field_x_qc_testset[$node->language][]['value'] = $testcase_testset;
                $node->field_x_qc_testcase_name[$node->language][]['value'] = $testcase_name;
                $node->field_x_qc_week[$node->language][]['value'] = $testcase_week;
                $node->field_x_qc_mrid[$node->language][]['value'] = $testcase_mrid;
                $node->field_x_qc_build[$node->language][]['value'] = $testcase_build;
                $node->field_x_qc_status[$node->language][]['value'] = $testcase_status;
                $node->status = 1;

                node_save($node);
            }
        } else {
            // no testcases on the current testset
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You could use the [Batch API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/group/batch/7) and create processes to handle your operations asynchronously. The progress bar will be automatically displayed as the processes are completed.

See an example here: [Using the Drupal Batch API](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/using-drupal-batch-api)

Comment: Thanks typologist. I looked at the example you gave me and I understand what is being done but I was unable to apply it to my code. I edited the question and now all the code is there. Can you (or someone) explain me how I adapt it to use the batch API? The loop is inside the function get_testsets($qc, $path) and also on xreport_qc_savedata($testsets) so that's the parts I need to have in batch. I think the code is simple, first part is basically the connection to HP ALM REST API, the rest is pure drupal. I would appreciate any help and direction on this one. Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to say that I don't want to use drush. Basically I just need this functionality without worrying about PHP timeouts and providing feedback on the progress of the operation.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw this. I answered your new question, explaining how to pass data between operations. Good luck!